# Wrong rfoot placing after setting \newgeometry

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, geometry

I have a document where from a certain point onward the width of the left margin changes. To do so, I used the `\newgeometry` command of the `geometry` package.

However, in the part of the document with the new value of the margin the right footer gets displayed in the wrong place. (Nonetheless, the left footer is placed correctly both before and after the change of the margin.)

Here is an example that reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.125in,top=1in,right=1in,left=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr}

\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\rfoot{Rfoot: Page number \thepage{}}
\lfoot{Lfoot: some text}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
Some text
\vfill
\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\newgeometry{margin=1.125in,top=1in,right=1in,left=1in}
Some other text
\vfill
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Here's an example of the correct behavior (before the margin change):

[image]

while here is the faulty behavior (after the margin change):

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suppose, that `fancyhdr` uses lengths at the moment of definition of a pagestyle. If the width changes, this won't alter the stored lengths. (untested)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I tried to repeat the code `\fancyhead{} ... \pagestyle{fancy}` after `\newgeometry`, too, but I still got the error.

Comment: Yes, that doesn't work due to the fact that `\headwidth` isn't updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fancyhdr` uses the 'command' `\headwidth` to set the width of the foot and head. This isn't updated by `\newgeometry`.

`\headwidth` is in fact a `\let\headwidth\fancy@headwidth`, i.e. the real length register is `\fancy@headwidth`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.125in,top=1in,right=1in,left=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr}

\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\rfoot{Rfoot: Page number \thepage{}}
\lfoot{Lfoot: some text}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
Old geometry: \verb!\headwith! is \the\headwidth

Some text
\vfill
\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\newgeometry{margin=1.125in,top=1in,right=1in,left=1in}
new geometry: \verb!\headwith! is still \the\headwidth
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}


Redefined: \verb!\headwith! is now \the\headwidth



Some other text
\vfill
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

**Update**

I have appended some code to `\newgeometry` that automatically updates `\fancy@headwidth`. This solves the problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}


\usepackage[margin=1.125in,top=1in,right=1in,left=2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum,fancyhdr}

\makeatletter
\let\@geometry@newgeometry\newgeometry

\renewcommand{\newgeometry}[1]{%
  \@geometry@newgeometry{#1}% Call regular \newgeometry first
  \setlength{\fancy@headwidth}{\textwidth}%
}
\makeatother

\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot{}
\rfoot{Rfoot: Page number \thepage{}}
\lfoot{Lfoot: some text}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
Old geometry: \verb!\headwith! is \the\headwidth

Some text
\vfill
\lipsum[1]

\clearpage
\newgeometry{margin=1.125in,top=1in,right=1in,left=1in}
new geometry: \verb!\headwith! is still \the\headwidth

Redefined: \verb!\headwith! is now \the\headwidth

Some other text
\vfill
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first answer worked, the second one did not compile on my system.  Perhaps geometry has changed since then. Simply inserting `\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}` after new geometry did solve problem. Hence I'm adding +1 for the original answer, not the update