# Controlling margins when using fancyhdr

Tags: fancyhdr

Good day!

[tex file for this problem](http://lyra.net/tex.rar)

It's a common question, and I read the proposed solutions, but I did not succeeded in reducing the bottom margin of my pages when using fancyhdr. I used the geometry package and this changed the layout of the page but some commands get obviously mixed up. I should add that I am an absolute beginner and that I am using a template preamble. Can somebody help? Thanks a lot

Here my attempted solution with geometry:

```
 \usepackage[left=2.5in,right=1.5in,top=3cm,bottom=4.5cm,headheight=1cm]{geometry}
```

The results 
with geometry
[image: with geometry]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable document, not only fragments we've to glue together

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I am not sure I can attach files so I linked to a zip file on the second line of my post. Cheers

Comment: @Fabbio : you can have a look on how to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (-; This will help us help you.

Comment: Load `geometry` before setting `\pagestyle{fancy}`.

Comment: This is perhaps related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297354/wrong-rfoot-placing-after-setting-newgeometry

Comment: Every template that has commands starting with `my` is a bad template and should not be used.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that template you are using is a mess!  Do you really need to use it?  It should be reworked!

Now to your file `main.tex`.  You have to change it to the following code (see the important changes marled with `<=======`):

```
\documentclass[18pt, a3paper, titlepage]{book}

\usepackage[%
  left=2.5in,right=1.5in,top=3cm,bottom=4.5cm,headheight=1cm
 ,showframe % <===================================== to show typing area
]{geometry}

\input{i10preamble.tex} % <================================= no \include

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\parindent}{20pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{3pt}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\begin{document}
\fontsize{12}{18}\selectfont
\sloppy

\vspace{30 mm}
\include{myChap1} % <=========================== cap1.tex does not exist!

\end{document}
```

In the preample you are not allowed to use command `\include`, use instead `\input{i10preamble.tex}`.

File `cap1.tex` does not exist. Change it to `\include{myChap1}`.

I inserted your call of package `geometry` at the beginning, to make sure that all other used packages can recognise the changed margings. Please note option `showframe` to visualize the typing area ...

The code of file `i10preamble.tex` calls different packages in the wrong order.  That should be corrected by the creator of that file ...

With the corrected file `main.tex` you get (change from page 1 to 2):

[image: change from page 1 to 2]

Answer (score 0):

try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bottom=2cm,footskip=8mm]{geometry}
```

Comment: That is what I tried already, it won't work because it messes up the margins. See pictures in my original post.

Comment: may be you need to use 
     \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt} instead of 0pt