# Header setting under \usepackage{fancyhdr} \pagestyle{fancy}

Tags: header-footer

[image]

[image]

In both the odd and even pages..."headrules"...means the horizontal line is not covering the full width of written texts as it is clearly visible from the uploaded images. The code of the chapter document which i have used is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead {}
\fancyhead [ER]{\footnotesize \sc Chernoff Distance for Conditionally Specified Models}
\fancyhead [OL] {\footnotesize\sc\rightmark}
\fancyhead [RO,LE] {\thepage}
\fancyfoot {}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,array}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\parindent 0.0 cm
\makeatletter \oddsidemargin 0in \evensidemargin 0in \textwidth
16cm \RequirePackage[dvips]{graphicx} \textheight 20cm
\setlength\textheight{8.8in} \setlength\textwidth{6.25in}
\setlength\topmargin{0.0in}
\newtheorem{t1}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{p1}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{l1}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{c1}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{d1}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{r1}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{co}{Counterexample}[section]
\newtheorem{ex}{Example}[section]
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%\newcounter{equation}[section]
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
```

I need help to solve the issue. Kindly help in your spare time...if the answer is known.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `fancyhdr` has a famous problem: It does not re-evaluate layout settings after changes, which brings us to the question: Why are you setting `\textwidth` explictly when you are using the `geometry` package? ...Try `\pagestyle` etc. and the `\fancy...` macros after the  layout settings.... and of course, your post is a fragment only

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297354/wrong-rfoot-placing-after-setting-newgeometry

Comment: "after changes"...which change is actually specified here??

Comment: `\setlength\textwidth` etc... Don't do this, as well not the weird `\makeatletter \oddsidemargin 0in \evensidemargin 0in ` usage

Comment: Thank both of you for your kind responses. Probably it has been solved by using the above correction.

Answer (score 1):

use it this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,rmargin=0in, lmargin=0in, 
   textwidth=16cm,textheight=20cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead {}
\fancyhead [ER]{\footnotesize \sc Chernoff Distance for Conditionally Specified Models}
\fancyhead [OL] {\footnotesize\sc\rightmark}
\fancyhead [RO,LE] {\thepage}
\fancyfoot {}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,array}
\parindent=0cm
\newtheorem{t1}{Theorem}[section]
[...]
```

then `fancyhdr` knows the exact page margins. Look into the documentation of `geometry` how pages can be defined. Margins of 0mm doesn't really make sense.